# C# Xamarin: How to center Text in a Listview

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

I have a problem with an App for Android.

I wrote an App, that lists Data in a ListView. The ListView only have a single Number per Row. So the ListView looks really empty and thats the Reason i try to center the Text in the middle of each Row.

My Layout.axml for the ListView looks like this:

```
        <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_km"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

I've addded:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

but it doesnt work. I've tried Layout_Gravity and Foreground_Gravity, too. Nothing is working.

Do you have an Idea to center the Text in each Row?

Comment: you can use custom list item layout with a TextView centering text

Comment: you need to center it in your row layout

Comment: Did the comment solved your problem? As Vlad Matvienko said, you can use custom list item layout.

Comment: Thank you very much, a custom list view is a lot of work but it worked in the end. Could be so easy if there is a gravity property to center the row, but it would be "to" easy ;D thank you once more